# Javascript and Rails Interaction

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new web development and am having some issues wrapping my head around how all the pieces of a Rails application interact. I'm using rails 3.2

Basically, what I am hoping to do, is to retrieve a response from a remote website that contains some uniquely formatted data. This data then needs to be parsed to pull out the important pieces, then these pieces need to be used to generate the partials on my page.

In the controller I have used:

```
require 'net/http'
@result = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse("http://remote.website.toget.data"));
```

The page is then initially rendered without the partials being generated. After this I use a script tag to parse the @result into arrays with the data I need:

```
var myData='<%= @result %>';
var myDataCleaned = myData.replace(/%20/g, " ");
while(gameTeams = regexGameTeams.exec(myDataCleaned)){
myTeams[count] = new Array();
myTeams[count][0] = gameTeams[1];
myTeams[count][1] = gameTeams[2];
count++;
}
```

Now I am confused as to how I can use this data to generate my partials. Researching shows that passing it in as a local to a <%= render 'partial' %> call is impossible, so how do I go about making this work? My guess is that I have gone about this the wrong way and need to somehow have the parsing done before rendering the page and then pass the result through the controller, but I can't seem to figure it out. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right, you should parse the data in ruby (in the controller that makes the remote call) and build your partials from that extracted data.
what format is the data in?

in case is `json`, you can just use `parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)`

but even if it is in a different format, ruby makes parsing relatively easy.

Comment: This makes more sense! Sadly the data is just a string of text, but I already have regular expressions to pull out what I need, I'll just have to adapt them to ruby. Thanks! P.S. once I have verified that this works as expected I'll select yours as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was to provide access to Rails/Ruby variables to Javascript within in the partial, then inside of the partial you'd do make it output JS code like:

```
some_js_var = <%= some_local_ruby_var_that_is_in_scope %>
```

or

```
some_js_var = <%= @some_instance_ruby_var_that_is_in_scope %>
```

You can't pass Javascript variables into Rails partials without making requests back to the server, so you'll want to do the response parsing, etc. on the server, or if you *have* to do the parsing in Javascript for some reason, then you'd setup some JSON service(s) on the Rails side to handle JSON requests from the JS side, but that would be a little silly.

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted my (probably poor) description. Since I am calling <%= render 'partial %> from within a script tag I could not find a way to pass the variables. I understand I can pass them from the controller, but since I'm already in the view I don't think it's possible. Thanks for the response anyways!

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks for the clarification- was thinking your question didn't match up to the question title... :)